# Assign coordinates to raster r

Tags: r, maps, coordinates, raster

I would like to assign `lonlat`to a `rasterbrick`, `r`. `r`was read from a `netcdf` file which had `latlon` in it. However, after reading the data, the metadata looks like:

```
class       : RasterBrick
dimensions  : 699, 639, 446661, 4779  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0.5, 639.5, 0.5, 699.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA

CRS=CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-97 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") # WRF proj4")
```

I then read in the `latlon` separately into `R`:

```
library(ncdf4)

ncname <- "file.nc"
ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc4", sep = "")
dname <- "tmp"  # note: tmp means temperature (not temporary)
# open a NetCDF file
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname, write = T)
print(ncin)
#---------
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "XLONG")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "XLAT", verbose = F)
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)
print(c(nlon, nlat))

[1] 639 699 639 699
```

You will notice that `nlon` and `nlat` has the same dimensions as `r`.
I don't want to `projectRaster`.

Question:

How can I assign the imported `lon` and `lat`to `r` such that the `extent` of `r` is `min(lon), max(lon), min(lat), max(lat)`?

I tried  `coordinates(dat)=c(lon,lat)` but it did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats wrong with `projectRaster`? Did you check `spTransform`?

Comment: @pat-s I already have lon and lat for the rasterbrick cells. What I want is a way to attach these latlon coordinates to each cell.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. Do you want to apply lat/lon (read in separately) info to an unprojected rasterbrick? Or set the extent of `r` to `nlat/nlon`? Still not fully understanding the question, I guess.

Comment: @pat-s Yes! I want to apply `lat/lon` (read in separately) info to an unprojected rasterbrick. Remember that lat and lon are read from same `netcdf` as `r`. I don't understand why raster package is unable to read lat and lon and show their `extent:-150, -52, 46, 72.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)` instead of `extent      : 0.5, 639.5, 0.5, 699.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`.

Comment: Did you try `raster::extent`? If this does not help you can also assign the extent values manually to the file (by addressing the specific slot directly). However you should still apply the correct projection to your raster besides the extent.

Comment: you can use `extent`  commnad `extent(r) <- c(min(lon), max(lon), min(lat), max(lat))` and than reprojec your raster `projection(r) <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')`